# calling virtual methods from within base class ctor

Tags: c#, oop

in C++ calling virtual method from within base class ctor will never call derived override.

in Java it does.

How about C#? (Don't have visual studio installed ATM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does in C# - the object is of its "final type" even while it's being constructed.

Just like in Java, this is a bad idea and should be avoided wherever possible, as you may be calling methods implemented at an inheritance "level" which hasn't been fully initialized yet for that object.

One difference in execution order between Java and C# is that in C#, instance variables with initializers, like this:

```
private readonly DateTime creationTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

... and initialized *before* the base class constructor executes, whereas in Java they're effectively executed just before the main body of the subclass constructor, *after* the superclass constructor executes.